# Как рекламные компании проверяют подлинность кликов по мобильной рекламе?

Tags: android, ios, mobile-development, admob, реклама

Как рекламщики проверяю подлинность кликов по встроенной в приложении рекламе? Например, если у приложения 1000 скачиваний, и какой-то ребенок или недоброжелатель начнет кликать на каждый баннер, есть ли вероятность что аккаунт забанят? Как вообще фильтруются эти клики и проверяются на подлинность?

Comment: "Как вообще фильтруются эти клики и проверяются на подлинность?" - для начала можно просто ip+cookies.

Comment: этот вопрос не имеет отношения к программированию, является слишком общим, и допускает более одного правильного ответа

Comment: и для поддержания дискуссии, вот вам статья по теме https://www.forbes.com/sites/thomasbrewster/2016/12/20/methbot-biggest-ad-fraud-busted/#78ca450b4899

Answer (score 1):

> И какой-то ребенок или недоброжелатель начнет кликать на каждый
>   баннер, есть ли вероятность что аккаунт забанят?

Вероятность этого события присутствует. Сам гугл рекомендует принимать превентивные меры.

[Вот](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342054?hl=ru&ref_topic=2745287) статья официальной документации.

[Вот](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3342099) официальные советы по предотвращению недействительных кликов

> Как рекламщики проверяю подлинность кликов по встроенной в приложении
>   рекламе?

Информации по алгоритму проверки подлинности кликов, насколько мне известно, в открытом доступе нет.

**Что говорит Google**

> Каждое нажатие на объявление AdWords проверяется нашей системой.
>   Недействительные клики выявляются с помощью специальных алгоритмов и
>   удаляются из вашего аккаунта.